# How to look-up data in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My simple python code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

names = pd.Series(['Bill','Bob','Joe','Sam'])
age = pd.Series([16,15,17,15])
weight = pd.Series([145,164,155,148])
df = pd.concat([names,age,weight],axis=1)
df.columns=['Name','Age','Weight']
[name,age,weight]=df.iloc[2]
# Now [name, age, weight] = ['Joe', 17, 155]
```

However, I don't know the index of 'Joe' and I need to find his [age, weight]. What is a good way to do that? Also, if I looked up the [age,weight] of 'Tim' I would want to know his name isn't in the DataFrame.

Comment: `df.set_index('Name').loc['Joe']`?

Comment: Alternative: `df.loc[df['Name'].eq('Joe'), ['age', 'weight']]`